# DRF permissions. In which cases bool(request.user) could be false?

Tags: django-rest-framework

So, i try to understand DRF source code and i noticed expressions like these:

```
return bool(request.user and request.user.is_staff)

return bool(request.user and request.user.is_authenticated)
```

All clear with 2nd part of expression, but for what `request.user` is?
I've tried this expression with GET request, but it always returns `True` either with anonymous, authenticated and admin user.
In which cases this could be `false`?

Answer (score 0):

```py
return bool(request.user and request.user.is_staff)
```

Here if will be False when user is not **superuser** or when he is not **not authenticated**

```py
return bool(request.user and request.user.is_authenticated)
```

For this, it will be False when user is not authenticated or not login to the system